# Convert RxJava Single to Mono

Tags: java, rx-java2, spring-webflux

I am new to RxJava and Spring webflux. Is there a way to convert RxJava Single to Mono?

I want to return a `Mono<String>` from the following function.

```
private Single<String> toNotification(PU update, Tx<PP> tx) {
    return findChannels(update.partyId(), update.notificationId(), tx)
        .toList()
        .flatMap(f -> Single.just("test"));
}
```

`findChannels` returns flowable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `reactor.adapter.rxjava.RxJava2Adapter.singleToMono(io.reactivex.Single<T> source)` which returns `Mono<T>`.

Source: [RxJava2Adapter](https://projectreactor.io/docs/adapter/release/api/reactor/adapter/rxjava/RxJava2Adapter.html)

Comment: `System.out.println(reactor.adapter.rxjava.RxJava2Adapter.singleToMono(Single.just("test")).block());` . <br/>

is giving the following error . <br/>

`java.lang.VerifyError: class reactor.adapter.rxjava.RxJava2Adapter$SingleAsMono overrides final method subscribe.(Lorg/reactivestreams/Subscriber;)`

Comment: Which version of these library are you using?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was using an old version and it was failing. The latest version works. Thanks!